# How to use conditionals to define a class?

Tags: python

I want to generate a `class` in which the number of input elements is determined by a conditional that is either `True` or `False`. I tried something like this

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond
        if cond == True:
            def __call__(self, a, b, c):
                d1 = a + b + c
                return d1
        elif cond == False:
            def __call__(self, a, b):
                d2 = a + b
                return d2

result1 = Test(cond=True)(a, b, c)
result2 = Test(cond=False)(a, b)
```

but it does obviously not work, and it provides the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Test' object is not callable
```

I suspect that I am using the wrong kind of `def`, as `__init__` is probably not suitable in this case.

- What is the most pythonic way to use a `class` in such a way?
- Is it even possible to do this using a `class`?

I know it would be fairly easy using a `def` function and not a `class`.

Comment: most pythonic could be one class without `if/else` and you send data as a list. Then you can send any number of values.

Comment: Also, just for elegance of code, you don't need to check whether booleans are True or False. The compiler replaces the variable name with its value upon evaluation. So insted of if(boolean_var == True): you can just do if(boolean_var):

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would restructure your code. It's not a good idea to add conditionals or logics into `__init__()` which serves only for initializing of variables.

Instead you should make the dunder `__call__()` separate so it can be called on the class instantiation.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond

    def __call__(self, a, b, c=0):
        if self.cond:
            return a + b + c
        else:
            return a + b

a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

result1 = Test(cond=True)(a, b, c)
result2 = Test(cond=False)(a, b)

print(result1)  # 6
print(result2)  # 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do conditional function definitions.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond

    def __call__(self, a, b, c=0):
        if self.cond:
           return a + b + c
        else:
           return a + b

a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

print(Test(cond=True)(a, b, c))
# => 6

print(Test(cond=False)(a, b))
# => 3
```

Also, don't do comparisons like `if cond == True:` and `elif cond == False:`, that's also an antipattern. If `cond` is supposed to be a Boolean value, `if cond:` and `else:` are perfectly fine.

Comment: Almost exactly same. :)

Comment: This forces you to always pass in `c`, though. Perhaps define it with a default `c=0`?

Comment: Thank you, @Tomalek, for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

A common way to avoid this in the first place is to define a subclass instead.

```
class Test:
    def __call__(self, a, b, c):
        return a + b + c

class Test2 (Test):
    def __call__(self, a, b):
        return a + b

result1 = Test()(a, b, c)
result2 = Test2()(a, b)
```

Superficially, this is hardly an improvement; but in situations where you might use a conditional in more than one place, this restructuring can pay itself back handsomely rather quickly.

Comment: Subclassing is neat!

Comment: This. If you can’t tell from looking at your *type* what arguments it will accept, you’re quickly painting yourself into a corner.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into metaclass stuff, the simplest way to implement that is to define `__call__` as accepting a variable quantity of arguments instead.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if self.cond:
            if len(args) != 3:
                raise ValueError('When cond=True, requires 3 arguments')
        else:
            if len(args) != 2:
                raise ValueError('When cond=False, requires 2 arguments')

        return sum(args)
```

Comment: @sleblanc, that still require you to change the condition. `len(args) != 3` -> `len(args) != 4` or something.

Comment: You can't change instance's `__call__` methods and expect `instance()` to behave differently. `instance()` will NOT run the instances `__call__` method, you either define it in the class, or it is a simply random method. You might as well call it bob and it would act the same.

Comment: @Austin, the point is a function using *args and **kwargs can be very flexible by only modifying the body of the function, while a function like `func(a, b, c=0)` cannot be modified to have tricky conditions like accepting a and c but have b empty.

Comment: @IşıkKaplan, you are right, I'll take this part out.

Comment: @sleblanc, does that first example actually work? If my condition is true and length is 3 means the code throws *"'When cond=False, requires 2 arguments')"*.

Comment: @Austin, oopsie, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can achieve the same result more pythonically by processing the arguments as a collection of arguments (thus skipping the initial configuration with your `cond`, since Python doesn't force you to have a fixed number of them), and either:

1. **Using a list as parameter:**

```py
class Test:
    def __call__(self, args):
        return sum(args)

my_test = Test()
print(my_test([1, 2, 3]))
# output: 6
```

2. **Use "varargs" to accept an arbitrary number of positional parameters:**

```py
class Test:
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return sum(args)

my_test = Test()
print(my_test(1, 2, 3))
# output: 6
```

Note that `*args` is effectively a list itself, the main difference is in how the callable is called.

Both of these work with any number of arguments. If you have specific behaviour corresponding to a specific amount of arguments, you can check the length of `args` as you would any list, and access its elements in the same way, for example with `args[0]`.

**If the initial configuration is required**, you can enforce a certain behaviour while still processing the arguments flexibly. For example, the following version of the class rejects input lengths different than 2 `if cond is True`, and inputs different than 3 if it's `False`, all with the same method:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if (self.cond is True and len(args) != 3) \
        or (self.cond is False and len(args) != 2):
            raise ValueError

        return sum(args)
```

You can of course add a default value to `cond` in the `__init__` if you want to make it possible to omit it when instancing the class.

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything in such a nice way that even an idiot like myself could understand it, @Federico S!

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `__call__()` is a function local to the `__init__()` method, so defining it there doesn't affect the `class`' definition. I don't know how "pythonic" it is, but the following seems like the simplest way to do what you want—essentially making `__init__()` act like a class decorator.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond
        if cond:
            def __call__(self, a, b, c):
                d1 = a + b + c
                return d1
        else:
            def __call__(self, a, b):
                d2 = a + b
                return d2

        setattr(self.__class__, '__call__', __call__)  # Assign to class.


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a, b, c = 10, 30, 2
    result1 = Test(cond=True)(a, b, c)
    result2 = Test(cond=False)(a, b)
    print(f'{result1}, {result2}')  # -> 42, 40
```

Comment: Thank you, @martineau. This is the closest one to what I was trying but I did not know `setattr` existed.

Comment: For the record, it's not very pythonic to do this, since costructing a class's methods in the `__init__` is generally not needed or desirable, makes the code less readable and dodges the usual syntax for defining methods. In short, it's too esoteric to be pythonic.

Comment: @Federico: It's no more abstruse than class decorators, which are an official part of the language—so doesn't seem that bad to me. I guess, like beauty, "pythonic" is in the eye of the beholder…

Comment: @naughty_waves: This approach is shorter and the result is slightly more efficient than it is in the answer you accepted (since the `cond` isn't checked every time an instance is called).

Comment: "Pythonicity" is indeed a mostly subjective matter, but I don't think crafting a method artificially like this should ever be done when there's more immediate and readable alternatives. Python doesn't require strict method signatures so why shouldn't the logic be simply integrated into a single method?

Answer (score 1):

While I would agree that perhaps other ways are *better*, if you remember that functions are first class objects in Python, then the most direct way of doing as close to what you have already done, is to redefine __call__ this way:

```
class Test:
    def method1(self, a, b, c):
        d1 = a + b + c
        return d1
    def method2(self, a, b):
        d2 = a + b
        return d2

    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond
        if cond:
            self.__call__=self.method1
        else:
            self.__call__=self.method2


Test(cond=True)(1, 2, 3)
6
Test(cond=False)(1, 2)
3
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gnudiff. I appreciate all the different solutions to my question.